# How to Count Number of Days Between Two Dates Using the Gregorian Calendar and While Loops

Tags: java, date, while-loop, gregorian-calendar

```
public class DVD implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected GregorianCalendar rentedOn;
protected GregorianCalendar dueBack;
protected String title;
protected String nameOfRenter;

public double getCost(GregorianCalendar ActualDatRented) {
    double cost = 3;
    double count = 0;
    if (ActualDatRented.after(this.dueBack)) {
        while(!dueBack.equals(ActualDatRented)) {
            count++;
            dueBack.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
            cost = cost + count;
            return cost;
        }
    }else if(ActualDatRented.equals(dueBack))
        cost = 3;

    return cost;
  }
}
```

This code is suppose to calculate the number of days between the dueBack and ActualDatRented and increase the cost by $1 for every day past the dueBack date. It doesn't need to be in a while loop but I thought it would be easier to write, but I do know that if written in a while loop it will have to loop through each day until the ActualDatRented is equal to the dueBack date and add the 1 to cost each loop. How do I make this code work?

Comment: What happened to the up to $50 limit?

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase.

Comment: Also, like Rick already mentioned in their answer, you should not use `Date` or `Calendar` classes, since they're obsolete. You should be using classes from the `java.time` package in new code. For instance, `DAYS.between` can easily calculate the number of days between two dates, so you don't have to do this yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, the reason why your code stops after one loop is the `return` statement at the end of the while loop. Also, if `dueBack` is the same as `ActualDateRented`, it will return 3, as per your else statement.

But there's a few other things wrong with this code. You're comparing `dueBack` with `ActualDateRented` by using `!=`, which for objects checks if they are both the exactly the same object, instead of comparing values. You should use the `equals` method to compare the dates.

In a more general sense, is there a particular reason why you're using `GregorianCalendar` instead of Java 8's Date/Time API? The 'new' API is a lot easier to use, and you don't need to write your own loops to determine the difference between days. You could check https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro for more info.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Count days.

```
ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( 
    myGregorianCalendar_Start.toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate() , 
    myGregorianCalendar_Stop.toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate() 
)
```

Compare.

```
if( 
     myGregorianCalendar_Start.toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate()
     .isBefore( 
          myGregorianCalendar_Stop.toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate()
     )
) { … }
```

Do math.  (untested code, use as a conceptual guide, actually need to specify rounding to the penny or tenth of a penny as dictated by your business rules)

```
new BigDecimal( "3" )  // Base cost.
.add( 
    new BigDecimal(
        ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(  // Calculate days overdue.
            myGregorianCalendar_Start.toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate() , 
            myGregorianCalendar_Stop.toZonedDateTime().toLocalDate() 
         )
    )
    .multiply(
        new BigDecimal( "1.5" )  // Daily overdue fee.
    )
)
```

## Details

The [Answer by Rick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53010660/642706) is correct and should be accepted.

As he pointed out, you are using terrible old date-time classes (`GregorianCalendar`) that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

The [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class is replaced by [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). You should avoid the old classes entirely. But when necessary to interface with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert using new methods added to the old classes.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myGregorianCalendar.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

and back again.

```
GregorianCalendar myGregorianCalendar = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

With a `ZonedDateTime` object in hand, you can extract the date-only portion, without the time-of-day and without the time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Calculate days elapsed using the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( ldStart , ldStop ) ;
```

Notice that the result is a `long` (64-bit integer), not a 32-bit `int`, so you may need to cast if mingling with other code expecting a `int`.

```
int days = ( int ) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( ldStart , ldStop ) ;
```

## `BigDecimal`

By the way, in real work, never use `double` or `Double` nor `float` or `Float` for money. Those types use [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) technology which [trades away accuracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) to get fast performance.

In any context where accuracy matters, such as handling money, use only the slow but accurate class [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).